# What do Ranges represent?

Tags: rust

The [Ranges](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) of Rust represent math expressions, but it's unclear from the documentation alone what they concretely do.

For example:

```rust
let foo = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let bar = &foo[1..=3];
```

Specifically, what are the differences between inclusion and exclusion?

Are there specific notations for the ranges `start < x` and `start < x < end`, so `start` is not inclusive?

Comment: [Range expressions - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/range-expr.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table that described the different types and what they include and not include.
This is based on the example for the docs.

| Type | Notation | Inclusion | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RangeFull | `( .. )` | `x` | `arr[ .. ]==[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` |
| RangeFrom | `(1.. )` | `start <= x` | `arr[1.. ]==[ 1, 2, 3, 4]` |
| Range | `(1.. 3)` | `start <= x < end` | `arr[1.. 3]==[ 1, 2 ]` |
| RangeInclusive | `(1..=3)` | `start <= x <= end` | `arr[1..=3]==[ 1, 2, 3 ]` |
| RangeTo | `( .. 3)` | `x < end` | `arr[ .. 3]==[0, 1, 2 ]` |
| RangeToInclusive | `( ..=3)` | `x <= end` | `arr[ ..=3]==[0, 1, 2, 3 ]` |
| No fixed type | see below | `start < x` | `____1____ ==[ 2, 3, 4]` |
| No fixed type | see below | `start < x < end` | `____1___3 ==[ 2 ]` |
| No fixed type | see below | `start < x <= end` | `____1__=3 ==[ 2, 3 ]` |

As [Stargateur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7076153/stargateur) defined below.
Manual ranges can also be defined using `Bound`(https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.Bound.html).
The last 3 cases can be defined as follows:

```rust
use std::ops::Bound::{Excluded, Included, Unbounded};
use std::ops::RangeBounds;

(Excluded(1), Unbounded).contains(&2) // start <  x
(Excluded(1), Excluded(3)).contains(&2) // start <  x <  end
(Excluded(1), Included(3)).contains(&2) // start <  x <= end
```

This is because [`RangeBounds` is defined for `(Bound<T>, Bound<T>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html#impl-RangeBounds%3CT%3E-1)

Comment: the last 3 can be represented with `(Bound::Excluded(start), Bound::*)`